# wxPython: GenericDirCtrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

i'm trying to display a directory tree within a panel in wxpython. I'm using this line of code for the purpose:

```
self.dir = wx.GenericDirCtrl(rightpanel, -1, dir='C:',
                                 style=wx.DIRCTRL_DIR_ONLY,
                                 size=wx.Size(60, 60))
```

but i get this huge error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\3pane.py", line 85, in <module>
app = MyApp(0)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 8628,    in __init__
self._BootstrapApp()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 8196, in _BootstrapApp
return _core_.PyApp__BootstrapApp(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\3pane.py", line 79, in OnInit
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'TAA')
  File "C:\Python27\3pane.py", line 55, in __init__
size=wx.Size(60, 60))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_controls.py", line 5663, in __init__
_controls_.GenericDirCtrl_swiginit(self,_controls_.new_GenericDirCtrl(*args, **kwargs))
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ..\..\src\common\intl.cpp(1449) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!
```

i really need help with this.

Thanks.